# How to use Postgres Pg_Tables - to compare contraints

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, view, constraints

I am developing a newer version of our system and some columns, tables, constraints and views are added and removed. I was able to use pg_tables to compare the columns with this query:

```
select 
    table_name, column_name
from 
    pg_tables 
join information_schema.columns on pg_tables.tablename = columns.table_name
where 
    schemaname = 'public'
order by 
    tablename, column_name;
```

But, I do not know how to compare the constraints of the tables. It is badly needed to implement them. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You usually need to query the catalogs to extract this kind of information:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html

The simpler way to learn it, is to run `psql -E` so as to show hidden queries. This will let you see the queries that `psql` executes when showing table informations (using e.g. `\d`). Optionally, wrap the queries in views as needed.

The following view, for instance, would yield check constraints:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS system;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW system.constraints AS
SELECT  con.conrelid::regclass,
        con.conname,
        con.conkey,
        ARRAY(
        SELECT  att.attname
        FROM    pg_attribute as att,
                generate_subscripts(con.conkey, 1) as k
        WHERE   att.attrelid = con.conrelid
        AND     att.attnum = con.conkey[k]
        ORDER BY k
        ) as conkey_names,
        pg_get_constraintdef(con.oid, true) as condef
FROM    pg_constraint as con
WHERE   con.contype = 'c';

COMMENT ON VIEW system.constraints IS
'Scans check constraints.';

SELECT * FROM system.constraints;
```

More views along the same lines here:

https://gist.github.com/ddebernardy/7893922